# How can you make multiprocessing remove it's self from a list

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to make a server (currently an echo server) that uses multiprocessing to handle the client connections.

Due to me wanting to be able to correctly close the connection to each client if the server goes down. I add all the connections to a list, unfortunately I can't think of a way that doesn't include wasting clock cycles or updating the list when a new client connects. To remove closed connections from the list.

I'm fine with how I would remove the process from the list which would be something like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(sock.rProcesses)):
    if not sock.rProcesses[i].is_alive():
        del sock.rProcesses[i]
```

As for my code it is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import socket, struct, sys, json
import settings

class ConnectionClient(Process):
    conn = None
    addr = None
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super(ConnectionClient, self).__init__()
        self.conn, self.addr = connection
        self.start()
        print 'Connected with ' + self.addr[0] + ':' + str(self.addr[1])

    def __send(self, info):
        print 'sending %s' % info
        self.conn.send(struct.pack('Q', len(info)))
        self.conn.recv(1)
        self.conn.send(info)

    def __recv(self):
        data = struct.unpack('Q', self.conn.recv(8))[0]
        self.conn.send(' ')
        return self.conn.recv(data)

    def _close(self):
        if self.conn != None:
            self.conn.close()
        print 'Disconnected with ' + self.addr[0] + ':' + str(self.addr[1])
        del self.conn, self.addr
        self.conn = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:data = json.loads(self.__recv())
            except:break
            if data[0] == 'QUIT':
                break
            else:
                try:self.__send(json.dumps(data))
                except:break
        self._close()

#This is used by the with statement, so that I know that everything will close
#even if I ctrl-c in console.
class socketHandler(object):
    s = None
    rProcesses = []
    def __enter__(self):
        for res in socket.getaddrinfo(settings.host, settings.port,
                                      socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, 
                                      socket.AI_PASSIVE):
            af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
            try:
                self.s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
            except socket.error as msg:
                print msg
                self.s = None
                continue
            try:
                self.s.bind(sa)
                self.s.listen(1)
            except socket.error as msg:
                print msg
                self.s.close()
                self.s = None
                continue
            break
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print 'Closing Socket'
        if self.s != None:
            self.s.close()
        for i in self.rProcesses:
            if i.is_alive():
                i._close()
        del self.s

with socketHandler() as sock:
    if sock.s == None:
        print 'could not open socket'
        sys.exit(1)
    #Now I multithread the connections, not very well.
    while True:
        sock.rProcesses.append(ConnectionClient(sock.s.accept()))
```

I don't really know if using Queues here is a good idea (I don't really know what they do). And I can only think of using a multiprocessed while loop, or checking after a connect, where I personally don't wish to use either. Or am I going about this all wrong? (This is for my A2 project so I'm a bit of a novice.)

The server doesn't allow IPv4 connections on my computer, so if you wish to have the client and settings (just local host and a port) here is a link: https://gist.github.com/Peilonrayz/ab693564145c53aa146c